# Debugging setup for C# service application with COM dependencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, hyper-v

I'm working on a C# code base that integrates with some legacy C++ code via COM registered on the system. Due to the difficulties of working with COM, the development environment at the moment is set up completely through a Hyper-V VM. The development tools (e.g. Visual Studio) are also on the VM. Basically we do nothing on the host machine. All development is done inside the VM. I think the main reason for this is if the COM registration gets messed up somehow, we can easily recover the OS by just deleting the VM and creating a new one.

I want to find a way to separate the development environment from the VM. Ideally, the need for the VM goes away entirely.

First I'd like to investigate a remote debugging option where the host machine is where Visual Studio 2019 is installed and the VM is only used for runtime testing / debugging. Basically the only things running on the VM would be the program I compiled + any COM libraries registered on the system.

When I did a similar set up for this years ago with C++, I remember compiling executables to a folder on the host that is mounted in the VM. From there, you use the remote debugging tools on the VM to launch a debug session (from VS on the host) using the path to the mounted folder.

For C# I'm not sure if a similar mechanism is available, nor am I sure if it is even feasible. Can anyone share their experience with a nice set up for this?

Ideally, the VM wouldn't be needed and instead I could "sandbox" the COM stuff from the host OS some other way. The less dependency on the OS the better I think, at least for debugging. Worth noting that normally this application runs as a windows service, and for debugging I try to run it as a console application.